# Expression to get average rows per minute from existing dataset

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a table driven off a dataset. The dataset contains a datetime column.
I have a textbox that I would like to display an Average of the rows per minute.

Trying to figure out the expression I can use that will do this without have to write another long running SQL query because the query in the dataset already takes some time to run.

I know yell at me for not providing code but i'm not sure how to go about this lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of rows divided by the difference in minutes between the minimum and maximum dates:

```
=Count(Fields!MyDate.Value, "MyDataset") / DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Min(Fields!MyDate.Value, "MyDataset"), Max(Fields!MyDate.Value, "MyDataset"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Derive a table with the grouped counts, and get the average from that:

```
SELECT AVG(MinCount)
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as MinCount
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY DATEPART(minute,MyDate)) as DerivedTable
```

Replace MyTable and MyDate with your table and datetime field respectively.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't see your Reporting Services tag!